Get value of a registry of windows with winreg on Python
I'm trying to get the value of a registry with winreg, but QueryValueEx returns me a PermissionError.
I have tried launching visual studio with administrator perms and launching the script with cmd with administrator perms, but I still get the PermissionError.
The code I have is the following:
import winreg
    
reg = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR", access=winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE) 
print(valor = winreg.QueryValueEx(reg, "Start"))

It doesn't have anything special, but I must be missing something or I'm not understandig how to use winreg correctly.

Can you try access with winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE?

Ok, that makes sense jaja. I didn't remember I could change the access type. It works now, thanks
